# Why is the command conn / as sysdba throwing an error in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Enter user-name: conn / as sysdba
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

[image: This is the screen shot of the error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: You've been prompted for a user name ("Enter user-name: "). You've entered a **connect** command ("conn / as sysdba"). That may, perhaps, explain the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

The special string `/ as sysdba` tells Oracle to use [OS Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/authen.htm#NTQRF327) instead of a username/password. Your OS (looks like Windows) is not authorizing you to connect to Oracle as sysdba.

Make sure your Windows user is a member of the `ORA_DBA` local group on that computer.

Comment: But it connects when I use the command "connect sys as sysdba"

Comment: `sys` is not `/`, is it?